# Why does a function show up as not defined

Tags: javascript, html, xslt

XSL:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('replaceAll(',$idS,');')"/>
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">replaceAll(ID0ED);</script>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    var cityNameRye = $("#spnCityID0ED").text().split(";")[1];
    if (cityNameRye.toLowerCase() == "rye") {
        //do something
    }
});
```

I get the following error in the console which causes an issue in the site:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: replaceAll is not defined
```

Can I create a dummy function which clears out the error?

Comment: replaceAll method doesn't exist in pure JS, hence the error. What do you want to achieve by using it? Changing String or replacing (deleting?) all occurences of element with particular id? If you want second one, keep in mind that you have to operate on JQuery object, e.g. $('<div>Element to replace #id with</div>').replaceAll('#id'). Here is API doc: https://api.jquery.com/replaceAll/.

Comment: I have a loop in the XSL file to go through many entries and I wanted to create an unique ID for each and then in the back-end strip the city only. I updated my question

Comment: Can you use JQuery? It would make solution easier :)

Comment: After looking at my XSL and JavaScript, can you please assist me in replacing the codes so it doesn't throw the error? I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this function code somewhere when it could be loaded before those from XSL are executed:

```
function replaceSpnCity(idPart) {
  var idsToReplace = $("[id^='spnCity']"); //updated missing quote
  idsToReplace.each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var newId = id.replace(idPart,'');
    $(this).attr('id',newId);
  });
}
```

And call it from XSL like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('replaceSpnCity(&apos;',$idS,'&apos;);')"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I have another error: `ID0ED is not defined` I don't think I can ever fix this :/ I can show you the page where it is showing the error.

Comment: You have to put additional quotes around $ID when doing concat, using &apos;, because function takes String as input parameter and you are trying to pass variable (without quotes). I adjusted my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have any function with the name replaceAll() in your code

try

```
function replaceAll(varName){
   //code to execute
}
```

and see if you still have the error

Comment: I have a loop in the XSL file to go through many entries and I wanted to create an unique ID for each and then in the back-end strip the city only. I updated my question. @Lau thank you but that didn't work for me :/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3fsye1qw/1/ Check here. If you run it in $(function(){}) that just executes on document ready with a closed scope. Also the id needs to be in between quotes since it is a string not a variable

Comment: I think I would need a function which returns the city. But I see where you are going with it...

Comment: The question you asked is why it is undefined :)